# What do you feed a skeleton horse on mcpe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

And yes I know how to tame them. I was riding my skeleton horse for the first time, and the hunger went down. A few minutes later my sister told that me he died. I'd like to know what they eat so that I can heal my new horse in the future.

Comment: I don't know about MCPE, but in PC MC, skeletal horses cannot be fed, and don't have hunger. Presumably, they can be healed with potions, but being undead, I'm not sure whether you'd use potions of healing or potions of harming. It's also worth noting that in PC MC, skeletal horses can't be tamed manually, you have to capture pre-tamed ones from a skeleton trap.

Answer (score 1):

In Minecraft pocket edition skeleton horses can not be fed but they can be healed with instant damage potions or instant damage tipped arrows.

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft bedrock edition or Java edition, it is currently not possible to feed skeleton horses. Although, if they take damage, you can heal them with any instant damage potions. This is because any undead mob in the game is healed by damage potions, and damaged by healing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot feed a skeleton horse. You do not really need to, because they regenerate health automatically. If you really want to heal it, then use an instant damage potion (it is undead, so healing and harming are reversed).